Unsatisfied Dependency Error: Missing TestService1 Bean in EmployeeController
I'm encountering the following error while running my EmployeeControllerTest class. I've been instructed not to modify the controller class. Could anyone please help me resolve this issue?

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '....controllers.EmployeeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'testService1': No qualifying bean of type '...services.TestService1' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
I have attempted the following approaches:
Using reflection to set private fields,
Constructor injection in the test class,
Creating a Test Configuration class to add the necessary beans,
Setting up dependencies manually,
I’m still unable to resolve the issue.
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfiguration.class})  
@WebFluxTest(controllers = EmployeeController.class)  
@Profile("local")  
public class EmployeeControllerTest {  
@MockBean  
private TestService1 testService1;  
@MockBean  
private TestService2 testService2;  
private WebTestClient webTestClient;  /* If I use @Autowired for this field, I'm getting an UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean due to an unsatisfied dependency expressed through the field 'webTestClient'.*/
@InjectMocks  
private EmployeeController employeeController;  
private JwtAuthenticationToken jwtAuthenticationToken;  
int pageIndex=0;  
int pageSize=10;  

@BeforeEach  
void setup(){  
MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);  
jwtAuthenticationToken = mock(JwtAuthenticationToken.class);  
when(jwtAuthenticationToken.getName()).thenReturn("testUser");  
/*If I don't use the code below, I get the error: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient.post()" because "this.webTestClient" is null.*/
webTestClient = WebTestClient.bindToController(employeeController).webFilter(new SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter()).build();  
}  
@Test  
void testEmployee(){  
Page<EmployeeDto> mockPage = new PageImpl<>(Collections.emptyList());  
when(testService1.list(eq(jwtAuthenticationToken), eq(pageIndex), eq(pageSize))).thenReturn(Mono.just(mockPage));  
webTestClient.post() .uri("/test/employee/{index}/{size}",pageIndex,pageSize).exchange().expectStatus().isOk().expectBodyList(EmployeeDto.class).hasSize(0);  
}}  

/*Controller Code:I've been instructed not to modify the controller class*/  
@RestController  
@RequestMapping("/test")  
public class EmployeeController {  
@Autowired  //Field injection is not recommended   
private TestService1 testService1;  
@Autowired  //Field injection is not recommended   
private TestService2 testService2;  
@PostMapping("/employee/{index}/{size}")  
public Mono<Page<EmployeeDto>> users(@NonNull JwtAuthenticationToken principal, @PathVariable int index, @PathVariable int size) {  
return testService1.list(principal, index, size);  
}  
}  


Can you format code for more easy to read? put it in ``` ... ```


Format the code in your question please. 1. What is in TestConfiguration. 2. Autowire webTestClient 3. Drop employeeController field 4. Drop openMocks call


MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this); is almost certainly the culprit. See "Misusing @InjectMocks" in https://stackoverflow.com/a/74027325/112968

@InjectMocks and @MockBean are generally not compatible. @MockBean is a Spring (Boot) annotation and @InjectMocks is a Mockito annotation.

Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74922201/nullpointerexception-when-running-service-test-with-mockito/74922393#74922393

The test runs successfully, as follows. Note that openMocks is not needed, neither is @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) that I had mentioned in an earlier version.

add @Autowired to the declaration of WebTestClient
(Important) remove initialization assignment of WebTestClient, since it is handled through injection above.
Use MockBean with private EmployeeController employeeController;.

Complete setup of test below, test cases omitted:
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfiguration.class})
@WebFluxTest(controllers = EmployeeController.class)
public class EmployeeControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private TestService1 testService1;

    @MockBean
    EmployeeController employeeController;

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    private JwtAuthenticationToken jwtAuthenticationToken;

    int pageIndex=0;
    int pageSize=10;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup(){
        jwtAuthenticationToken = mock(JwtAuthenticationToken.class);
        when(jwtAuthenticationToken.getName()).thenReturn("testUser");
        //do not use: WebTestClient.bindToController
    }

    @Test
    void testEmployee(){
        Page<EmployeeDto> mockPage = new PageImpl<>(Collections.emptyList());

        when(testService1.list(eq(jwtAuthenticationToken), eq(pageIndex), eq(pageSize))).thenReturn(mockPage);


        webTestClient
                .post()
                .uri("/test/employee/{index}/{size}",pageIndex,pageSize)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk().expectBodyList(EmployeeDto.class).hasSize(0);
    }

}

With this solution you cannot use SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter; it would be tested separately.
Regarding the pom.xml, with this configuration the above test works, including the assertions, as is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>xa.xa.xa</groupId>
    <artifactId>plain</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>plain</name>
    <description>plain</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>




If I use @Autowired on webTestClient, I'm getting an org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '.......controllers.EmployeeControllerTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'webTestClient': No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)} error.

Hello. If you use @WebFluxTest(controllers = EmployeeController.class), then you would automatically get WebFluxAutoConfiguration, then WebTestClientAutoConfiguration, which defines bean WebTestClient. Have you emulated the example exactly as given?

Yes, I have emulated the example exactly as given, but I'm still facing the same issue.

pom.xml: spring-boot-starter-webflux and spring-boot-starter-test included?

Yes, I have already included it.

Please list the contents of TestConfiguration

@Target({ElementType.TYPE})     @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)     @Documented     @Configuration     @TestComponent     public @interface TestConfiguration {     @AliasFor(     annotation = Configuration.class     )     String value() default "";     @AliasFor(     annotation = Configuration.class     )     boolean proxyBeanMethods() default true;     }

I replaced the configuration file, and it worked.

Super, happy you could figure it out.

Your code isnt formatted well, making it a bit hard to understand. I would recommend you to use a code formatter for Java to improve readability.
Anyways, I have identified a few things in your code that could be fixed. Let's go through each one, one by one:
1. Remove @InjectMocks for EmployeeController:
While using @WebFluxTest, Spring will create an instance of EmployeeController and inject the mocks defined by @MockBean. The @InjectMocks annotation in your test class might be causing a conflict.
2.  Set up WebTestClient as an @Autowired Field:
Since you’re using @WebFluxTest, you can let Spring autowire the WebTestClient. This client will be configured to work with the mocked version of EmployeeController, including all @MockBean dependencies.
3. Removed @Profile("local"): This willl avoid any potential issues with profile based conditional loading in the test context.
Here is the code after those changes:
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfiguration.class})
@WebFluxTest(controllers = EmployeeController.class)
public class EmployeeControllerTest {  

    @MockBean  
    private TestService1 testService1;  

    @MockBean  
    private TestService2 testService2;  

    @Autowired  
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;  

    private JwtAuthenticationToken jwtAuthenticationToken;  
    private final int pageIndex = 0;  
    private final int pageSize = 10;  

    @BeforeEach  
    void setup() {  
        jwtAuthenticationToken = mock(JwtAuthenticationToken.class);  
        when(jwtAuthenticationToken.getName()).thenReturn("testUser");  
    }  

    @Test  
    void testEmployee() {  
        Page<EmployeeDto> mockPage = new PageImpl<>(Collections.emptyList());  
        when(testService1.list(eq(jwtAuthenticationToken), eq(pageIndex), eq(pageSize))).thenReturn(Mono.just(mockPage));  

        webTestClient.post()
                .uri("/test/employee/{index}/{size}", pageIndex, pageSize)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .expectBodyList(EmployeeDto.class)
                .hasSize(0);  
    }  
}  

I hope this helps with the dependency error. Feel free to ask questions if any. :)

Did you by any chance had an LLM write this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/help/gen-ai-policy

Again no. wrote it myself. Used a code formatter to 'prettify' the code.
Why do you keep commenting the same thing on every answer?
